# Relation Between Activity and Its Layout in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-activity, mobile-application

In Eclipse, anytime that I create a new Activity in my Android app, in addition to the Java Activity class, a companion layout xml file is also generated. Obviously, I could generate 10 layouts and switch the Activity's layout between these 10 anytime I want.

So, my question is why this layout is being generated; is it generated for convenience or is it a good practice to always have a specific layout associated with the Activity?

Also, does an Activity always have to have a layout, or that I could have an Activity that never uses a layout.

Comment: **"does an Activity always have to have a layout"** - Your question suggests you don't really understand the concept of the Android `Activity` class and its purpose in Android. Its purpose is to act as a UI framework and although it is possible to create views for an `Activity` programmatically, the usual approach is to use an XML  layout file which makes UI design more flexible and allows re-use of the layout in other `Activities` (if necessary). The Android `Activity` class isn't just a standard Java class and without a UI, it has little or no purpose.

Comment: You are correct in that I don't really understand the Activity class.  I have learned a lot about Android in the last few month, but I know that I have a long way to go.  Thanks for your explanation; it makes it much more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From android reference:**

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost
>   all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes
>   care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with
>   setContentView(View).

This process of creating a window is costly operation and you should only call setContentView-once in your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

- If you feel the need to add xml-resources you can use a [layout inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). (tip: always pass a container reference to the inflater)
- If you feel the need to use more then one layout file (a whole new ui), you should consider creating a new [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

**About your questions:**

> So, my question is why this layout is being generated; is it generated for convenience or is it a good practice to always have a specific layout associated with the Activity?

Convenience, you are using a wizard for creating an Activity. In most cases you will implement an XML resource for your Activity, so the wizard creates it for you.

> Also, does an Activity always have to have a layout, or could I have an Activity that never uses a layout?

It is not required to have a layout for an Activity, but a window will be created. An example of this is a splash screen Activity where you show an image but do not set a content View.